# function generator

Tags: function-generator

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgxaFA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

First, I set the output terminal of function generator to 50ohm and output voltage amplitude to 8Vp-p. Then I change the terminal to Hi Z and removed the 50ohm load. Why does the displayed voltage of the function generator became 16Vp-p while the voltage displayed on oscilloscope remain 8Vp-p?

It is a Agilent 33220A function generator and DSO-X 2002A oscilloscope.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of the scope?

Answer (score 1):

We had these in collage years ago, the *High Z* and *50 Ohm* is just software. I can't remember what direction is right but one setting just multiplied or divided the real voltage by a factor of 2.

Trust the scope.